# Перекодировка из base64 в hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, base64, hex

Стоит достаточно тривиальная задача, перевести строку из base64 в hex. 
Подскажите функцию Python 3.++ или 2.++ которая решит данную задачу

Comment: Сначало перекодировать в байты, а потом в heх, можно частями, надо понимать что один символ base64 кодирует 6 бит, а байт состоит из 8, не хватает 2 бита. 8/2 = 4, т.е. 4 символа накопят полный байт, т.е. 6*4 = 24, 8*3 = 24, т.е. 4 символа base64  дадут 3 байта или 6 символов heх. Можно декодировать порциями кратно 4 символам.

Answer (score 1):

Через `b64decode` получаем байтовую строку, что была закодирована в `base64`, а у байтов вызываем `hex` для получения строки в `HEX`:

```
import base64

text_base64 = b'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'
# OR:
text_base64 = 'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'

text = base64.b64decode(text_base64)
print(text)
# b'Hello World!'

print(text.hex())
# 48656c6c6f20576f726c6421
```